# AlertDialog закрывается при автоповороте

Tags: java, android

Заметил недавно, что любые окна из `Dialog` на android api закрываются при автоповороте, даже имея `setCancelable(false)`.

Как можно это исправить?
Помню как-то, через манифест, решал проблему с активностью, а как с `Dialog`?

Comment: `setCancelable()` не имеет никакого отношения к автоповороту и сохранению состояния

Answer (score 2):

Не рекомендуется решать проблему пересоздания активити / закрытия диалогов отключением этого механизма в манифесте. В этом случае приложение будет падать при других изменениях конфигурации, например, при подключении usb/bluetooth клавиатуры.

setCancelable(), если мне не изменяет память, лишь запрещает "быстрое" закрытие диалога нажатием кнопки "назад".

Я использую (возможно, это плохое решение)

```
taskDialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), TAG_TASK_DIALOG);
```

для отображения диалогового окна (благо в моём приложении оно может быть только в одном экземпляре) и

```
taskDialogFragment = (SimpleProgressFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG_TASK_DIALOG);
```

для получения диалога после пересоздания активити.

В общем-то, буду благодарен, если кто-то предложит лучшее решение.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я знаю, это решается только сохранением состояния и восстановлением после поворота. Т.е. нужно это предусмотреть в коде, показать диалог снова.